# How to be directed to page automatically?

Tags: android

I am writing a calculator. There are main 2 modes: polish and reverse polish system.
Anytime MainActivity is called, I like the MainActivity to direct the user to the correct page.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent;
        String CalculatorMode = Memory.getPreference("CalculatorMode", this);
        if (CalculatorMode.equals("Calc_reverse"))
            intent = new Intent(this, Calc_reverse.class);
        else
            intent = new Intent(this, Calc_normal.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

After the user is directed to Calc_normal.class or Calc_reverse.class, and if he pressed the back button, he get back to the MainActivity. But nothing happen! The onCreate() is no more called. How to fix this, and is there a better way to write this? I am trying to learn, and any help is very welcome.

Comment: there is nothing wrong here.. maybe its in your manifest post it

Comment: The `onCreate()` method is not usually called when the user presses the Back button.

Comment: If you want this code to be executed when user pressed back button inside Calc<> activities, move this code from onCreate to onResume method. onResume will be called anytime when the activity be shown. But this behavior is not good, because you prevent user to exit from app in common way.

Comment: Oh my... you are so right. I totally forgot to let people to exit my program. Of course, it would be nice if they use my software for life. Never mind, I am going to make sure they can exit.

Comment: You have to @override onResume  methode for geting action at resuming activity.

Comment: same as writtem by @Demand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of onCreate() you can call your methods in onStart() which will be called anytime you navigate.

onCreate() won't be called unless the activity is destroyed, you can check the activity lifecycle.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

onStart() activity will be visible to user but won't interact.